How can I compute the cross product of some sets of ordered pairs?
I have a list of sets of ordered pairs:
{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 8}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}}

There are 4 ordered pairs in the first set, 2 ordered pairs in the second set and 2 ordered pairs in the third set.  I want the 4X2X2=16 triplets of ordered pairs:
{{{1,1},{1,1},{1,1}}, {{1,1},{1,1},{1,2}}, {{1,1},{1,2},{1,1}},..., {{4,8},{1,2},{1,2}}}.

I tried using the functions "Outer" and "List" but my code didn't work.

Please include the code you tried, so that we can see where you are!

Like this Outer[List, Sequence @@ lst, 1]~Flatten~2? Where lst is your list of lists of ordered pairs.

@ march.  Yes   Thank you.

input = {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 8}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}};
Tuples[input]

